# SQL Server : big data replication primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, database-replication, sql-server-2017

I know that this subject has been discussed may times but there are different opinions about it. My scenario is this I have created a database which is going to be filled with 4 billion records and each year will be added between 1 to 2 million records.

We have servers in the USA and Europe and we do replication of the database to keep them similar on these servers for example same thing that Facebook does with replication.

My question is this as a primary key of the tables what should I use - `BigInt` or `Uniqueidentifier`, or it does not make any difference what I use for the replication?

1. Should I create a non-clustered `uniqueidentifier` primary key and then add another clustered `bigInt` column?

Or

2. Should I create a clustered `bigint` primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt, go with a `Uniqueidentifier`.

Do not add a `bigint` column, you don't need it.

If you use merge replication and you don't have a uniqueidentifier then the server is going to add that column anyway.

By using a GUID, you now have the capability of setting up a multi-master DB architecture.  If you use a bigint as an identity field then you either force yourself to only use a single master (to control the bigint) or you then have to come up with a scheme to keep multiple servers from colliding with each other.  Further by using GUIDs you get away from guessable IDs - which is generally a good thing.

My own testing in the hundred million record range with millions added / deleted *daily* showed no performance drop when using GUIDs vs ints for ids.

Final note - most places base64 encode the guid when calling web services or if it is going to be displayed anywhere - like in the address bar.

Comment: but did you create cluster index on the guid pk?

Comment: Using a  `GUID` as the clustered primary key wrecks havoc on your performance - and wastes a **whole lot of disk space** in the process, too! The more data you have - the worse it gets. Read [Disk space is cheap .....](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/disk-space-is-cheap/) and basically everything by Kimberly Tripp to get a good understanding of **why** that is the case. And btw: adding a `BIGINT` clustered index *might actually SAVE you lots of disk space!* - don't dismiss that right from the get go !

Comment: @marc_s so what is your opinion should i use a bigint with clustered index and pk or a guid column with non-clustered index and then add an other column bigint with clustered index.

Comment: @Whiplash : see my response - if I could choose, I'd pick a single, clustering key on a `BIGINT IDENTITY` column

Comment: @marc_s so correct me if i understood wrong so you will chose to create a bigint as data type primary key as clustered and don't create the uniqueidentifier column. By using Bigint wont cause me isues with copy data replication right?

Comment: @marc_s: I understand what you are saying, and I've read the links in your response.  However, all I can do is fall back on my own experience which is that GUIDs aren't the *performance nightmare* that people often claim.  Maybe OPs database doesn't have a multi-master requirement.  Maybe having guessable IDs isn't a potential security problem.  Maybe a few hundred MB of extra data actually has an impact on their servers.  I could see that being a concern 10 years ago (date of those articles) when spinning drives were a thing and 64GB of ram was a lot for a DB server.  Not today.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue just the other option: I would try to **AVOID** `uniqueidentifier` columns - **MOST DEFINITELY** as your clustering key!

The clustering key is the *most replicated* data structure in SQL Server - and with millions and millions of rows, it does makes a **huge** difference if your clustering key is 8 or 16 bytes in size. Not to mention the number of page splits a `uniqueidentifier` clustering key would introduce - which you can totally avoid with a clustering key of `BIGINT` type.

If you're really interested - you **must read** all these articles from Kimberly Tripp - the "Queen of Indexing" in the SQL Server space - that clearly shows just how bad and counter-productive a GUID as your clustering key can be:

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/)
- [The clustered index debate continues...](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)
- [More considerations for the clustering key – the clustered index debate continues!](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/more-considerations-for-the-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again!](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/)
- [Disk space is cheap .....](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/disk-space-is-cheap/)

Comment: I know that Cluster on guids is bad for performance and disk space. since i have to do copy replication on the EU server of the database should i use Guid As primary key but with NON_CLUSTERED index and then create an other column with data type bigint and do the clustered index on that colum. Or if i create Bigint as primary key as CLustered index will cause me issues to do replication

Comment: Which option will you choose if you had a table with 4 billion records and need to do copy data replication on other server?

Comment: @Whiplash: sorry, I'm not familiar with replication and any requirements it might have, so I can't really tell you here. From a performance point of view, a single `BIGINT` column as PK+CK would be best; if that doesn't work, use GUID for NON-clustered PK, and create the clustering key on a `BIGINT` , in my opinion